# How to fix a leaking faucet aerator

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet

I removed the aerator on my kitchen faucet and attached a hose for a time and cleaned the aerator.  Now I cannot get the original one to screw back into the place without it leaking (well spraying mostly).  Any suggestions on ways or tools to get an aerator firmly back in place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there any chance you've cross-threaded it?  If you're sure it's not cross-threaded, then I'd check for a missing washer or O-ring.  It may have blown out of the aerator when you were backflushing it with the hose.

Comment: I've accidentally dropped the rubber washer down the drain before when cleaning crud out of the aerator.  If you think you lost one, check the drain trap!

Comment: I found the problem. The washer had gotten stuck to the faucet threads, then stuck on the aerator/hose adapter. Once I found it and put it in place everything sealed up nicely.